# Генерация результата футбольного матча

Tags: алгоритм, java

Добрый день!
Я ищу алгоритм, который по 1 критерию(рейтинг команды, рассчитанный по методу Эло) может подсчитать и вернуть результат матча(естественно, вероятностный).
К сожалению, гугл мне не помог(

PS Для генерации кол-ва голов можно использовать случайное число , рассчитанное оп нормальному распределению. За сигму можно взять разницу сил команд(абсолютное значение)

Comment: @voipp, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, что у вас не получается и т. д.

Comment: @Free_ze более подробно написал в комментарии к посту @Nofate ♦

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что такое "сила команды"?

Вообще для подобных целей обычно используют [рейтинговую систему Арпада Эло](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%BE). Вкратце: при проигрыше рейтинг падает, при выигрыше - растет. Имея рейтинг 2х сторон, можно оценить шансы на победу каждой стороны.

Comment: сила команды - как раз ее рейтинг(по системе Эло). А мне надо смоделировать матч и получить результат.

Answer (score 0):

boolean win = myTeam.getPower() > oppositeTeam.getPower();

Comment: результат - это счет